# How to initialize mysql in nginx.conf for openresty in lua

Tags: mysql, nginx, lua, openresty

I am using redis and mysql for openresty project where i am trying to initialize the db with init_worker_by_lua but i have received below error.

my db.lua code:

```
    local mysql = require("resty.mysql")                   -- Introduce mysql
    local redis = require("resty.redis")                   -- Introduce Redis
    local db, err = mysql:new() 
    if not db then
        ngx.say("failed to instantiate mysql: ", err)
        return
    end
    local ok, err, errcode, sqlstate = db:connect{
        host = "127.0.0.1",
        port = 3306,
        database = "employee",
        user = "root",
        password = "password",
        charset = "utf8",
        max_packet_size = 1024 * 1024,
        }
```

below is the nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log logs/error.log;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    init_worker_by_lua_file /Users/rahulgarg/work/conf/db.lua;
    server {
    listen 8082;
        location ~ ^/api(.*)$ {
             default_type 'text/html';
             add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json';
             access_by_lua_file /Users/rahulgarg/work/conf/auth.lua; 
             content_by_lua_file /Users/rahulgarg/work/conf/dbapi.lua;
            }
        }
    }
```

ERROR received while running openresty -p `pwd`/ -c conf/nginx.conf:

```
[error] 72436#1634105: 
init_worker_by_lua_file error:
...ebrew/Cellar/openresty/1.19.3.1_1/lualib/resty/mysql.lua:1094: 
API disabled in the context of init_worker_by_lua* stack traceback: 
[C]: 
in function 'tcp'
...ebrew/Cellar/openresty/1.19.3.1_1/lualib/resty/mysql.lua:1094: 
in function 'new'
/Users/rahulgarg/work/conf/db.lua:4: in main chunk
```

Any solution how can we resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After debugging, I have found an answer. In case anyone else stuck at the same point. I have created a module of db.lua and made following changes.

```lua
local mysql = require "resty.mysql"

local _M={}

function _M.connect()

    db, err = mysql:new()
    if not db then
        ngx.say("failed to instantiate mysql: ", err)
        return
    end

    db:set_timeout(1000) -- 1 sec

    local ok, err, errcode, sqlstate = db:connect{
        host = "127.0.0.1",
        port = 3306,
        database = "employee",
        user = "root",
        password = "password",
        charset = "utf8",
        max_packet_size = 1024 * 1024,
    }

    if not ok then
        ngx.say("failed to connect: ", err, ": ", errcode, " ", sqlstate)
        return
    end

    ngx.say("connected to mysql.")
    return db
end

return _M
```

I have done same configuration for redis as well and created a separate module for redis. and added both in the init_worker_by_lua block in nginx.conf and it worked. Please let me know if you have any questions.